# Why are serialized numpy random_state objects different when are loaded?

Tags: python, numpy, random, seed

I'm trying to figure out why certain cross-validations using a defined set of indices, the same input data, and the same `random_state` in `sklearn` gives different results using the same `LogisticRegression` model hyperparameters.  My first thought was that the initial `random_state` may be different on subsequent runs.  Then I realized when I `pickle` the `random_state` it says the objects are different when I compare the 2 objects directly but the values in the `get_state` method are the same.  Why is this?

```
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
print(random_state)
# <mtrand.RandomState object at 0x12424e480>

with open("./rs.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(random_state, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
with open("./rs.pkl", "rb") as f:
    random_state_copy = pickle.load(f)
    print(random_state_copy)
# <mtrand.RandomState object at 0x126465240>
print(random_state == random_state_copy)
# False
print(str(random_state.get_state()) == str(random_state_copy.get_state()))
# True
```

Versions:

numpy= '1.13.3',

Python='3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]')

Comment: Bonus: Any insight to the LogisticRegression cross-validations being different.  I'm using `saga` solver.  Could that be why?

Comment: It appears that numpy's `RandomState` class does not implement equality testing, so it gets the default behavior that is based on object identity alone.  Your unpickled object is certainly not the *same object* as the one originally pickled, so the comparison returns False even though every detail of the two objects is equal.  (My guess as to the actual problem: your computations are somehow, sometimes using the global (shared) random state rather than the provided one.)

Comment: Please show the complete code of LR with cross-validation.

Comment: It was an error on my part where the cross-validation indicies were offset in terms of the Logistic Regression.

Answer (score 1):

The unpickled copy of initial random state in your example actually produces the same sequence of random numbers (tested on python 3.6, numpy 1.15.4).
Probably the equality testing is not implemented for `RandomState` as @jasonharper pointed out. `==` returns `False`, but the states are identical in behavior.

Following code fragment inserted after your code provided in question:

```
a = random_state.randint(0, 10, 5)
b = random_state_copy.randint(0, 10, 5)
print(a)
print(b)
print(a==b)
```

Produces:

```
[5 0 3 3 7]
[5 0 3 3 7]
[ True  True  True  True  True]
```

So, most likely, not the `RandomState` makes the run results different: look for causes of differences somewhere else.